# Tessa voice completely fails to read sentence, how to avoid this error

Tags: text-to-speech

Mac OS X 13.2.1

Lately, I have been having trouble with some voices on my Mac mispronouncing words depending on context.  An example is the word *headlines*, which is pronounced correctly by itself, but is mispronounced by an assortment of voices (e.g. Kate) in this sentence:

**Just last week, a Federalist Society event at Stanford Law School made national headlines after protesters heckled U.S. Circuit Judge Stuart Kyle Duncan, a Trump appointee to the Fifth Circuit, causing him to cut his remarks short.**

I've been fixing these issues as they crop up by giving the offending words alternate or phonetic spellings which somehow evade whatever the bug is.

But now I've stumbled over a sentence that one particular voice won't read at all.  This command produces no output, audio or otherwise.

**say -v 'Tessa' 'Just last week, a Federalist Society event at Stanford Law School made international headlines after protesters heckled U.S. Circuit Judge Stuart Kyle Duncan, a Trump appointee to the Fifth Circuit, causing him to cut his remarks short.'**

That is, replacing the word *national* with *international* in the problem paragraph produces something completely unreadable for Tessa.  Using the 'Tessa (Enhanced)' voice produces the same result.  Curiously, if I change *international* to *enternational*, the voice can read the sentence but it skips the next two words after *enternational*.

My question is, are these voice modules complete black boxes?  A mispronounced word is easily detectable in playback, a dropped sentence or paragraph isn't.  I need an error code or an exception thrown to let me know that something has gone badly wrong so that I can choose another voice in those cases.

Update: The bugs are still present in Sonoma 14.1.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but please report this via "Feedback Assistant."

Comment: @WGroleau Thanks, done.